# How to scale Highcharts height on window resize with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, highcharts

I have this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sjyuej?file=Chart1.jsx
where I'm trying to make the the two charts in the left container share the height and respond to window resizing.

I've made the width responsive by setting overflow: hidden, forcing the charts to rescale as far as I understand, but I don't know how to get the same effect with the height.

Setting height='100%' in the Chart component doesn't help.

Comment: Hi Matsomo, I recommend you to use `highhcarts-react-official` wrapper, which in easy way allow you to use default Highcharts options and methods: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

Comment: Hey, I updated my example to better illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lknnch
I'm trying to make the chart and table share the space equally.

I tried the official wrapper as well, but my problem is that I can't find a way to make the height scale

Answer (score 17):

Use the [highcharts-react-official](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) package (>= 2.1) and set `containerProps={{ style: { height: "100%" } }}`.

This will make the chart dynamically resize to fill its parent div. You can then set up parent divs using flexbox to get your desired layout.

For example your render method would look like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      containerProps={{ style: { height: "100%" } }}
      highcharts={ Highcharts }
      options={ options }
    />
  );
}
```

[Here is a live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wqrqbw?file=ChartOfficial.jsx)

Make sure you are on version >= `2.1` of highcharts-react-official ([see this github issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react/issues/72))

Answer (score 0):

After setting the `height`, you need to use `chart.reflow()` method:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const container = this.chartComponent.current.container.current;
  const table = document.getElementsByClassName('table')[0];

  container.style.height = table.clientHeight + 'px';
  this.chartComponent.current.chart.reflow();
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#reflow

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3jwwvt?file=ChartOfficial.jsx

Comment: why my data gets empty after reflowing?

Comment: @Afsanefda - Could you reproduce the problem in some onlince code editor?

Comment: thanks the problem solved (I think it was the way I select the chart by useRef - My sample was react BTW)

Comment: I have another question about data labels in the treemap. Could you please help me with that if I share the question url?

Comment: Hi @Afsanefda, Sure - just create a question with `highcharts` tag.